# Recursive query unexpectedly returning a blank value for one field

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb, recursive-query

I have the following tables:

```
persons:
- personid: int not null
- personname: varchar(200) not null

parents:
- parentid: int not null
- personid: int not null
```

One person may have children, in which case there are rows in the `parents` table, where each row identifies a parent/child relationship.

I now have the following recursive query:

```
        WITH RECURSIVE cte (personid, parentid) as (
            -- Anchor query
            SELECT
                personid AS personid,
                NULL AS parentid
            FROM
                persons
            WHERE
                personid = ?
            UNION ALL
            -- Recursive query
            SELECT
                p.personid,
                p.parentid
            FROM
                parents p
            INNER JOIN
                cte ON p.parentid = cte.personid
        )
        SELECT
            parentid,
            personid
        FROM
            cte
```

The anchor row is given the ID of the `person` to start with. I want this query to select that person as well as all his children, recursively.

But it doesn't work: the query returns the expected number of rows, however the `parentid` field is always blank (!), except for the first row where the value is `NULL` (which is what I want). The value of the `personid` column seems correct for each row.

How is this possible that the value of `parentid` be empty? What am I doing wrong?

I'm using MariaDB 10.5.19. MySQL 8.0.27 exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: I tried to test with MariaDB 10.5 and MySQL 8.0, and it seems to work correctly: https://dbfiddle.uk/WjAsmHa8 Can you provide a dbfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I see you're using CAST(NULL AS UNSIGNED) instead of NULL, and it works for you, which is great, thank you. I believe this was the problem. If you replace with NULL, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is in the first part of your recursive query:

```
        SELECT
            personid AS personid,
            NULL AS parentid
        ...
```

The data type for parentid is determined by this. The type becomes NULL instead of the required INT. In a UNION, a column may have only one name and one data type, which apply to all subsequent rows appended by other queries in the UNION.

When the second part of the recursive query tries to put integers into that column, it fails.

When I tested the query given I run in strict mode, I get this error:

> ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'parentid' at row 1

If one were to run the query without strict mode, the value is truncated to some zero-ish value. I tested in MySQL 8.0 and got `0x` in the result.

MariaDB may have different behavior. We should all stop thinking of MariaDB and MySQL as compatible products. They have an increasing number of incompatible behaviors. They are effectively totally different products by now.

The solution is to make sure the base case defines that column with the right data type:

```
        SELECT
            personid AS personid,
            CAST(NULL AS UNSIGNED) AS parentid
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Can I ask why CAST(NULL AS INT) is inappropriate?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but in MySQL and MariaDB, `CAST(<expr> AS UNSIGNED [INTEGER])` or `CAST(<expr> AS SIGNED [INTEGER])` is the supported syntax. In other implementations of SQL, you can use other names for the data types. It must have made sense at the time.